# How can I use a custom build of CKEditor 5 with React and Vite?

Tags: vite, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

For the past several months, I've been building my app with Create React App.

However, Ionic now supports Vite and I am attempting to migrate my app from CRA to Vite.

Originally, I made a [CKEditor 5 Custom Build](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) and set it up in a React app like this:

```
import React from 'react';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore  Ckeditor does not supply TypeScript typings.
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore  Ckeditor does not supply TypeScript typings.
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
```

Before building my app, I build the custom CKEditor like this:

`cd ckeditor5; npm run build`

The CKEditor build command is `webpack --mode production`.

Now, after configuring Vite, when I run `npm run build`, I get the following error:

> 'default' is not exported by ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js, imported by
> src/components/contentTypeCard/CKEditorInput.tsx

The CKEditor issue queue has a [thread on a lack of documentation on issues with Vite](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/9807), but there's nothing in particular about how to resolve this issue.

#### What I tried

I tried building CKEditor in development mode (`webpack --mode development`) and examining the `ckeditor.js` file to try to export Editor, but the file has over 100,000 lines of code and I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by integrating the custom CKEditor build with my Vite build process.

What I did:

First, open the `package.json` from the custom build (the one with the name of `ckeditor5-custom-build` and copy the `depedencies` to your project's `package.json`.

Next, make a config file based on `src/ckeditor.ts` from the custom build.

I put mine in `editorConfig.ts`:

```
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline';

    const editorConfig = {
      fontSize: {
        // Excludes "tiny" and "huge".
        options: ['small', 'default', 'big'],
      },
      plugins: [Bold, Essentials, FontSize, Link, Paragraph, Underline],
      toolbar: [
        'bold',
        'underline',
        'fontsize',
        '|',
        'link',
        '|',
        'undo',
        'redo',
      ],
    };
    
    export default editorConfig;
```

Then, use the CKEditor component like this:

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import editorConfig from '../../constants/CKEditor/editorConfig';

  <CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    config={editorConfig}
    data={myData}
  />
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case it:

"react": "18.2.0",
"vite": "2.9.10",

**Here is the solution that I found**:

package.json

```
"ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:libs/ckeditor5",
```

vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['ckeditor5-custom-build'],
    },
    build: {
      commonjsOptions: { exclude: ['ckeditor5-custom-build'], include: [] },
    },
  };
});
```

RichTextEditor.tsx

```
import { CKEditor, CKEditorProps } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';

export function RichTextEditor({
  defaultValue,
  ...props
}: RichTextEditorProps) {
  return (
    <EditorContainer>
      <CKEditor editor={Editor} data={defaultValue || ''} {...props} />
    </EditorContainer>
  );
}
```

**Update for vite 4.4.8:**

"vite": "4.4.8",

vite.config.ts

```
import commonjs from "vite-plugin-commonjs";

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      react(),
      commonjs({
        filter(id) {
          if (["libs/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js"].includes(id)) {
            return true;
          }
        },
      }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ["ckeditor5-custom-build"],
    },
    build: {
      commonjsOptions: { exclude: ["ckeditor5-custom-build"] },
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the CKeditor 5 custom build by going to the folder containing CKeditor5.

webpack.config.js

Delete:

```
output: {
    // The name under which the editor will be exported.
    library: 'ClassicEditor',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'ckeditor.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default',  
 }
```

Add:

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'ckeditor.js',
    library: {
      type: 'module',
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  }
```